# How to loop certain aspects of a program

Tags: c++, loops, user-input

I'm trying to loop the assignment scores and totals based on whatever the user inputs in for `n`. I have been searching around and just hitting duds, which is what the whole deal with the `int i` variable is at the moment. I can't get things to loop properly and right now this doesn't even compile because of that pesky `i` I have in there. You take out that `i` and the program runs fine with the exception that nothing becomes of the `n` input.

```
/**
File: project_2_14.cpp
Description: Write a program that calculates the total grade for N classroom exercises as a percentage. The user should input the value for N followed by each of the N scores and totals. Calculate the overall percentage (sum of the total points earned divided by the total points possible.) and output it as a percentage. Sample input and output is shown below.
Created: Friday, September 11th, 2015
Author: 
email: 
*/

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    float s;  // assignment score
    float t;  // total points worth
    float p;  // percentage     
    int n = 0;

    //input the number of assignments

    cout << "How many assignments are there? " << endl;
    cin >> n;

        for (int i=0; i < =n; i++)
        {


    //input the total points earned for assignment
    cout << "What is the score earned for this assignment? ";
    cin >> s;


    //input the number of points assignment is worth
    cout << "How many points was the assignment worth? ";
    cin >> t;

    //calculate percentage
    p = (s / t)*100;
        }


    //output score

    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);
    cout << "Total score: " << p << "%"<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the int n = 0; and it should be simply int n.

and you should use <=, without any spaces between both characters.

EDIT:
As you can see here: http://ideone.com/SeNum8 it already loops correctly :)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    float s;  // assignment score
    float t;  // total points worth
    float p;  // percentage     
    int n;

    //input the number of assignments

    cout << "How many assignments are there? " << endl;
    cin >> n;

        for (int i=0; i <=n; i++)
        {


    //input the total points earned for assignment
    cout << "What is the score earned for this assignment? ";
    cin >> s;


    //input the number of points assignment is worth
    cout << "How many points was the assignment worth? ";
    cin >> t;

    //calculate percentage
    p = (s / t)*100;
        }


    //output score

    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);
    cout << "Total score: " << p << "%"<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're right about the space between < and =, but there's nothing wrong with int n = 0;

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only problem I'm running into is that the program loops one more time than inputted no matter what. Why would that be? I can't see anything in the code that would lead to that. (I'm using http://cpp.sh to compile the code.) I also think it's only calculating the final grade.

Comment: Okay I changed `for (int i=0; i <=n; i++)` to `for (int i=1; i <=n; i++)` and that solved the error where it was adding on an extra prompt.